# Error in Gitlab: git configured for git user ... no try fixing it

Tags: gitlab

Until today evening everything was working fine. I don't how server goes down, some one would have turned off but after I restart server and lxc container where gitlab is used to run, I tried to access gitlab by the server IP:192.168.2.9(container IP) in browser I get response as `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.2.9`. I check in server as `service gitlab status` it shows gitlab is up and running.

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

Git configured for git user? ... no 
Try fixing it: 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name "GitLab" 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitbum@xxxx.xx"
For more information see: doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab" 
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

Then I checked `doc/install/installation.md` file I find these two line

```
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name "GitLab" 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitlab@localhost"
```

then I changed it to

```
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name "git" 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitbum@xxxx.xx"
```

and checked `config/gitlab.yml` there the email_from already set as `gitbum@xxxx.xx` and default user as `git`. run again same line and get same error again

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

Git configured for git user? ... no 
Try fixing it: 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name "GitLab" 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitbum@xxxx.xx"
For more information see: doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab" 
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

Then I did `sudo su -git` and did `git config --list`

user.name=GitLab
user.email=gitlab@localhost
core.autcrlf = input

I tried to find any occurrence of `gitlab@localhost` inside home/git/gitlab, I don't find andy occurrence of `gitlab@localhost` except some logs fine and `gitlab.yml.example`.

I tried to find any occurrence of `gitlab@localhost` inside home/git/ here I found `gitlab@localhost` in `/home/git/.gitconfig`. In .gitconfig I see

[user]
name = GitLab
email = gitlab@localhost
[core]
autocrlg = input

and changed to

[user]
name = git
email = gitbum@xxxx.xx
[core]
autocrlg = input

Now when I run `git config --list`

user.name=git
user.email=gitbum@xxxx.xx
core.autcrlf = input

but when I run

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get same error again

```
Git configured for git user? ... no 
Try fixing it: 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name "GitLab" 
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitbum@xxxx.xx"
For more information see: doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab" 
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

I checked every time with restart the gitlab again and again. I have now I idea whats happen suddenly. What I did when I start the server was started the git container from `LXC Web panel`. Any help?

**UPATE**

I found the occurrence of `user.name GitLab` in `howe/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake` file and chanded `GitLab` to `git`. now when I run  `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production`

I see the result is

> Git configured for git user? ... yes

but still I don't get gitlab up when I try to access from browser. what would be the problem?

Comment: have you found a solution jet? I am stuck at this point too :(

Answer (score 0):

the email address you set for `email` field in `.gitconfig` needs to match the `email_from:` value in `config/gitlab.yml`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error occurring in my setup, and the answers provided here pointed me in the right direction. The email address of the default git user should be set to the same value as your `gitlab_email_from` field. In my case, the `gitlab_email_from` field was a different value from what they use as the default. So, in my *gitlab.rb* file, I have the following lines:

```
# Set the email address for the default git user
user['git_user_email'] = 'email@address.com'

{...}

# Specify the address from which to send email
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'email@address.com'
```

After making this change, doing a **gitlab-ctl reconfigure** fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I was having a similar problem and was able to fix it by checking this [Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/Q2d5K_8b4DI%20%22newsgroup). To sum up the important parts :

Make sure the values in /var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig  match the ones in gitlab.yml

Answer (score -1):

According to this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/Q2d5K_8b4DI), the fix is to use the same e-mail address in your git command as in your /home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml file.

Hope this helps!